# Finding object key and deleting it

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I'm trying to find a specific object key and delete it, but I cannot find a way of doing it.

Example:

```
{
    Tree: {
        apples: "green",
        color: "brown"
    },

    House: {
        windows: "transparent",
        flowers: "Bupleurum"
    }
}
```

I would like to find the `House` object and delete it, so I will be left only with the `Tree` object.

```
{
      Tree: {
         apples: "green",
         color: "brown"
        },
}
```

I tried the following function from other stack overflow question but it didn't work

```
function filterObject(obj, key) {
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            filterObject(obj[i], key);
        } else if (i == key) {
            delete key;
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

I'm new to JavaScript and any help will be appreciated!

---

**UPDATE**

I managed to do what I wanted with the examples you gave me, thank you! What I will also like to be able to do, is to delete multiple object keys.

Example

```
 var myHouse =  {
        House: {
            windows: "transparent",
            doorColor: "red",

             Kitchen: {
                 tableColor: 'silver',
                 forks: "silver"
              },

             Garden: {
                 flowers: "Bupleurum"
               }
        }
    }
```

I want to delete from `House` object, the `Kitchen` object and the `Garden` object, so later I will be only left with the `House` object.

```
var myHouse = {
            House: {
                windows: "transparent",
                doorColor: "red",
            }
        }
```

I tried to do it in the following way using lodash utility library, but it didn't work.

```
_.unset(myHouse, ['House.Kitchen', 'House.Garden']);
```

From what I saw in the documentation, is possible to pass path of an array into the unset function. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#unset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash provides the [**unset**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#unset) function which will also work on nested objects:

```
// remove Tree
_.unset(obj, 'Tree');

// Remove House.windows
_.unset(obj, 'House.windows');
```

**UPDATE**

[**omit**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit) can be used to remove multiple keys from a single object:

```
myHouse.House = _.omit(myHouse.House, ['Kitchen','Garden'])
```

[**omit**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit) doesn't change the object on which it acts so here we're setting the value of `myHouse.House` to the new object.

Comment: Actually, that's what I'm doing now. I'm trying to make it work with a array, but for now is not working `dash.unset(localeFile, ['common.companyDetails', 'common.helloomay']);
var badKeys = localeFile`

Comment: So you have an array of objects and you want to remove the same property from each object?

Answer (score 2):

If the property you want to delete is not nested in another one, you can do just

```
function filterObject(obj, key) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        delete obj[key];
    }
    return obj;
}
```

or even without the check - JavaScript won't complain if it can't find a property to delete.

Comment: This works thanks, but it will be also nice to work with nested objects. Can you show me how to do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple

```
delete ExampleObject['House']
```

or

```
delete ExampleObject.House
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ak8xentw

Answer (score 0):

with the use of **for in loop** (Keep it simple) :

```
var ExampleObject={
    Tree: {
        apples: "green",
        color: "brown"
    },

    House: {
        windows: "transparent",
        flowers: "Bupleurum"
    }
};

for (var index in ExampleObject) {
 if(index==="House"){
    delete ExampleObject[index];
    }
 }

console.log(ExampleObject);
```